# How do I fix cookie returning null in JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

I know similar questions on the stack reference this issue, but I looked at them and they did not help. I am a beginner.

I have a site where I would like to store the user email in a cookie to allow them access to some content. Here is the structure

PageA.html (I set the cookie using the following code I saw on quirksmode.org)

After the user logs in (enters their email and password and the server says all good regarding their credentials), this command is executed

```
createCookie("useremail",'account@somewebsite.com',0);
```

and then the user is taken to PageB.html where some action takes place. PageB.html has this code that attempts to read the cookie set earlier on PageA.html

```
readCookie('useremail');
```

but that results in null. When I go back to the previous page, I check the cookies in Chrome, and I indeed see the cookie. But, when I go to PageB.html, it is not there. Below is the code I referenced.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=somewebsite.com/projectX/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}
```

For reference, both pages are on the same domain (somewebsite.com/projectX/PageA.html and somewebsite.com/projectX/PageB.html). Additionally, this happens on an actual app hosted on a webserver, not testing from localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It turned out an issue with the path parameter value. I replaced

```
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=somewebsite.com/projectX/";
```

with

```
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/;
```

And that did it.